# installing and running django on windows 8

Tags: python, django, selenium

I am a complete newbie in Web Development, I am currently a Preschool Teacher and trying to switch careers. I am enrolled in Interactive Web Design 221 well I was I had to drop the class because I could not seem to figure out how to properly install and configure Django, Selenium, and Geckodriver for Windows 8. I have uninstalled and reinstalled Python, Django, Selenium several times but I still can't get Django to run when I type:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://localhost:8000')
assert'Django'
in browser.title
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "functional_tests.py", line 6, in <module>
    assert 'Django' in browser.title
AssertionError
```

This doesn't work and 
`$ django-admin.py startproject superlists` this command doesn't work either.
As I said I am a complete newbie at this stuff, and I am not sure why this doesn't work. 
A step by step instruction on getting all of this installed properly with the correct paths and to make sure I am installing the correct versions.

Comment: Hi Karen! This problem seems a little unclear to me, you could try to follow the DjangoGirls guide! Their explanation of the code/python/web development is very good and easy to follow if you're a beginner like you stated. Also perhaps, look into using virtual environments for the development of code! Try looking at tools such as VirtualBox and Vagrant with Ubuntu, this will save you so many configuration problems!

Comment: I'm not familiar with "Interactive Web Design 221", but the selenium and superlists sound very similar to the "Test Driven Development with Python" book. Are you following  [these instructions](http://www.obeythetestinggoat.com/book/pre-requisite-installations.html)? You need to activate the superlists virtual environment (`workon superlists`) before `django-admin.py` will work. As Anna suggests, the [Django Girls tutorial](https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/) might be a better one to start with.

Comment: Hi Alasdair that is the current textbook we are using. However, I have tried several times to get this to run, everything is downloaded on my computer even pip install Django, and Selenium worked. After getting everything installed and even setting the path in environment variables the commands wouldn't work. Thank you for helping me out with this question! I really appreciate it.

Comment: Hi Anna, Thank you so much for helping me work through this! I have spent so many late nights and early morning for the past 5 days and still could not get it to run. I know it is me forgetting to do something but I just can't figure it out. I appreciate your help and will try anything.

Answer (score 1):

I started playing with webdev tools in windows too. It was a bad experience. The versions, dlls, the windows blackbox! Stuff didn't work I didn't know why. So I spent several hours trying to fix stuff and it finally worked, but I still didn't know why.
Linux is more complicated at start. Pretty steep learning curve. But in the long run its totally worthwhile, because I didn't just got stuff to work. After a while I started to understand why stuff worked.

So, here is my crash course. I use [cloud 9 IDE](https://c9.io/), an online IDE that comes with an ubuntu 14 server installation. Go there, make an account, open a fresh workspace (choose blank, not django) and you will get a nice text editor and an UNIX terminal.

Python comes with every Linux distribution, so no need to install that. 
Go make a python virtual enviroment, which saves a lot trouble with different versions of libraries.

Type this in your terminal:

```
sudo pip3 install virtualenv  
mkdir yourproject
cd yourproject
virtualenv -p python3 env
source env/bin/activate
```

sudo is for admin rights. pip is your python best friend, which installs all libraries (3 is for python 3). virtualenv is a library that set a separate enviroment for your development, so it does not pollute the operating system.
Now you have your python 3 project enviroment set.

Then install django:

```
pip install django
```

Because you are in your enviroment, no need for sudo or 3 on pip. This is installing django in the local project folder. Then start your project:

```
django-admin startproject myproject
```

That's it. Go enjoy the best docs out there:
[Django Girls](https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/pt/),
[Official tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/)

If you don't like cloud 9, or get tired of the online lags, install ubuntu 16 (with GUI) in your computer, or in a [virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) in your windows installation.
My advice with selenium. Don't start with it. It's intermediary stuff. On the server install you have to run it headless, install chrome...  it's complicated. Make the basic tutorials, get used to ubuntu and django, then go back to selenium after a week or two.

Another thing that helped me a lot was [Udacity courses](https://br.udacity.com/course/web-development--cs253/). Presencial courses are soooo 1990's  :)

Pretty opinionated answer, but I hope it helps.
Cheers.

Comment: Hi Tico, Thank you so much for your help. If only the instructor of my class was like this maybe I could actually learn something instead of banging head on table and ripping hair out. He decided since I didn't have Windows 10 he couldn't help! I am willing and want to learn how to do these things. I can't thank everyone enough for all of your help!

Comment: Hey!  Glad to help!